# ElasticSearch: How to write query where string field is either null or empty?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to check for documents that have `media_url == '' || media_url == null`. I have a query:

```
{
    "engagements": [
        "blah"
    ],
    "query": {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 2,
        "sort": [
            {
                "bookmarked": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            },
            {
                "created_at": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }
        ],
        "facets": {},
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "car_id": "78778"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "created_at": {
                                        "gte": "2015-04-12T04:00:00.000Z",
                                        "lte": "2015-05-13T03:59:59.999Z"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "media_url": ""
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "bookmarked": false
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "word_frequencies": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "text",
                    "size": 150
                }
            }
        },
        "highlight": {
            "fields": {
                "text": {
                    "fragment_size": 1500
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "api": "_search"
}
```

However, if I do what I do above, then records that are set to null wouldn't be returned. What should I do to return records with either '' or null as their media_url value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you can try using the "or" filter.
http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-or-filter.html

```
{
  "or": [
    {
      "term": {
        "media_url": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "media_url": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit: Here's the full query (untested since I don't have an example document/index template)

```
{
    "engagements": [
        "blah"
    ],
    "query": {
      "from": 0,
      "size": 2,
      "sort": [
         {
            "bookmarked": {
               "order": "desc"
            }
         },
         {
            "created_at": {
               "order": "desc"
            }
         }
      ],
      "facets": {},
      "query": {
         "filtered": {
            "query": {
               "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "car_id": "78778"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "range": {
                           "created_at": {
                              "gte": "2015-04-12T04:00:00.000Z",
                              "lte": "2015-05-13T03:59:59.999Z"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "or": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "media_url": ""
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "media_url": null
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ],
                  "should": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "bookmarked": false
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "aggregations": {
         "word_frequencies": {
            "terms": {
               "field": "text",
               "size": 150
            }
         }
      },
      "highlight": {
         "fields": {
            "text": {
               "fragment_size": 1500
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "api": "_search"
}
```

Comment: Hi where exactly would I place this in my query string??

Comment: Updated my reply, let me know how it goes or update your question with example document and mapping.

Comment: The correct answer was using `missing: { "field": "media_url" }` instead of `"media_url": null`, but still going to accept your answer since it's almost correct! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [missing filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-missing-filter.html) to take care of null value or field itself is missing. You can combine the same with an empty string term to achieve what you want.

```
{ 
   "or": [
    {
      "term": {
        "media_url": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "missing": {
        "field": "media_url"
      }
    }   
    ]
}
```

Use the above instead of the single term query for "media_url" in the must clause of your Boolean filter.

Comment: The missing filter has, erm, gone missing since 5.something

Comment: @doctorlove thanks for pointing out. We can use the exists query under a "must_not" clause for the same effect

Comment: @PrabinMeitei but how would you use that inside the "or" (which is now "should")? I can't figure out the proper nesting.